# What is the best way to create Android library project and use it as a jar file in another project using Android Studio

Tags: android, jar, android-library

I have referred few of the link to know the procedure to create an Android library project, none of them have completely explained in detail. My intention is to create a Android library(**ex mathsolve.jar** ) project and distribute it as a .jar file so that others can use it in their android app.

Can any one please explain the below steps in detail

**a)** How to create a Android library project

**b)** How to export that Android library file as .jar file

**c)** Steps to integrate that .jar file to Another android app

**d)** And how to call a method of that .jar file from that android app

Any suggestion will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/

Comment: "How to export that Android library file as .jar file" -- an Android library project creates an AAR, not a JAR. "Steps to integrate that .jar file to Another android app" -- publish the AAR to a Maven-style repository (e.g., a local repository on your development machine), then have the other app use `repositories {}` and `dependencies {}` to reference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally with the help of few post from statckoverflow and by doing trial and error method I am able to get the solution to my question. Here are steps

**a) How to create a Android library project**

step 01>  In Android Studio go to File -> New -> New Module

step 02>  Select Android Library and click on "Next" button
[image]

step 03> Choose minimum SDK supported and click on "Finish".
[image]

step 04> A new Module will be added and wait until the gradle sync. Now your library file is created

**b) How to export that Android library file as .jar file**

step 01> After completion of stage "a" you need to build the project once and you are done . The .aar file will be created in the path of your Android app -> Module Folder ->  build -> outputs -> aar -> module-release.aar

step 02> You just need to copy that module-release.aar and distribute it where ever you want.

**c) Steps to integrate that .jar file to Another android app**

step 01> Here the library type is in .aar format . The steps are same for both .jar file and .aar file. In Android Studio go to File -> New -> New Module

step 02> In that New Module window select "import  .JAR/.AAR Package" and press "Next" Button
[image]

step 03> A new file browser window will open . Here in "File name" section choose file browse and open your module-release.aar file and click on "Finish"

step 04> After successful build copy following compile statement into Your "App module gradle file"

```
dependencies {
  compile project(path: ':module-release')
}
```

step 05> Sync the gradle file.

step 06> If any, copy all permission given to your library file to your App Manifest.xml. Thats all you are done

**d) And how to call a method of that .jar file from that android app**

step 01> In your module you need to define a public method which can be accessible using class name . For example

```
public final class MyAPI {
    public static int SumOf(int a, int b){
           return a+b;
    }
}
```

step 02> And from your Host App you can call the SumOf method using

```
MyAPI.SumOf(2,4);
```